# how to install java 8 in ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: java, 16.04, jdk

How to install java-JDK 8 & maven in Ubuntu 16.04 without adding any PPA?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Open a terminal (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>):

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8*
```

This will install the folowing packages:

```
openjdk-8-jre-dcevm - Alternative VM for OpenJDK 8 with enhanced class redefinition
openjdk-8-jre-zero - Alternative JVM for OpenJDK, using Zero/Shark
openjdk-8-dbg - Java runtime based on OpenJDK (debugging symbols)
openjdk-8-demo - Java runtime based on OpenJDK (demos and examples)
openjdk-8-doc - OpenJDK Development Kit (JDK) documentation
openjdk-8-jdk - OpenJDK Development Kit (JDK)
openjdk-8-jdk-headless - OpenJDK Development Kit (JDK) (headless)
openjdk-8-jre - OpenJDK Java runtime, using Hotspot JIT
openjdk-8-jre-headless - OpenJDK Java runtime, using Hotspot JIT (headless)
openjdk-8-jre-jamvm - Alternative JVM for OpenJDK, using JamVM
openjdk-8-source - OpenJDK Development Kit (JDK) source files
```

Now to `maven`:

```
sudo apt-get install maven maven*
```

This will install the folowing packages:

```
maven - Java software project management and comprehension tool
maven-ant-helper - helper scripts for building Maven components with ant
maven-debian-helper - Helper tools for building Debian packages with Maven
maven-repo-helper - Helper tools for including Maven metadata in Debian packages
```

Comment: Why the wildcards? Isn't it enough to install `maven` and `openjdk-8-jdk`? It is totally unnecessary to install `openjdk-8-source` for example...

Comment: @GerhardBurger It gives you JavaDocs and standard library browsing in IDEs like Intelij.